# How to use css focus?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am familiar with using css and the 'hover' feature but I am interested in knowing how to use an on click feature.

So to begin with to use the hover feature you can have:

```
#test {
background: black;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

and then when the mouse 'hovers' over I want it to turn white

```
#test:hover {
background: white;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

So is the a similar way of changing the background on click?

Thanks!

James

Comment: So... focus or hover? Your tags and question are a little confusing.

Comment: You probably need to use javascript to change the css class of the item when it is clicked. I don't think this can be done with just css.

Comment: Do you want the bg-color to stay changed after the click? or is it just while being clicked?

Answer (score 3):

The psuedo selector `element:focus` is used generally for when an element has focus. Like when you are typing inside a textarea or input.

As you can see in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/rJW35), `button:focus` doesn't make the `background-color` any different onClick.

To make it change while being clicked, use the `element:active` pseudo selector:

```
button:active
{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/rJW35/1/).

Answer (score 0):

> So is the a similar way of changing the background on click?

You can use javascript for this.

Simpliest thing is to use some jquery

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    css('background','green');
});
```

You can also change the class of an item once clicked.  This way you can store the css in your styelsheet.

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('greenBackground');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is slightly vague but current CSS specs only provide the following related pseudo-classes:

- [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3Aactive) - Applies briefly while the element is being clicked
- [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afocus) - Applies while the element is focused (mouse or not)